# В чём разница между min-width и flex-basis?

Tags: css

В чём разница между min-width и flex-basis?

Comment: [min-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/min-width), [flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis).

Answer (score 1):

1) С помощью width, min-width, max-width Вы манипулируете шириной дочерних элементов.
А с помощью свойств flex-shrink и flex-grow Вы распределяете между элементами недостающее или свободное пространство родителя соответственно при его недостаче или избытке.

2) Также, данные свойства влияют на элементы одинаково при изменении главной оси со "строки" на "колонку". Если же Вы зададите элементам ширину, например, 50%, а потом измените flex-direction на column, элементы начнут выстраиваться в колонку (друг под другом), но их ширина станет лишь 30% от родителя.
Это же касается и свойства "flex-basis", которое имеет преимущество в определенных ситуациях перед "width".

3) Никто не запрещает использовать "width".